# Netbeans 7.0.1 rspec support?

Tags: ruby, netbeans, rspec

i have a problem with rspec and Netbeans 7.0.1. I try to run a rspec test but so far i can't convince Netbeans to do so. I just don't get any output at all although i installed all the necessary rspec gems. Unit tests run perfectly though.

Do I have to install Netbeans 6.8 or am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solution is to maunally install Rspec, since Netbeans doesn't have RSpec Version 2 support:

```
gem install rspec -v 1.3.2
```